# In Google Apps Script, debug tool says e is undefined? Script doesn't work when editing in sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

The function in question:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var spreadSheet = e.source;
  var sheetName = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var column = range.getColumn();
  var inputValue = e.value;
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet(); if (sheet.getName() !== 'By Type' && sheet.getName() !== 'By State')  {return;}
  if(sheetName == 'By State' && column == 7)
  {  
     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('By Type').getRange(range).setValue([inputValue]);    
  } 
  if(sheetName == 'By Type' && column == 7)
  {  
     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('By State').getRange(range).setValue([inputValue]);    
  } 
}
```

isn't e already defined? What do I need to change?

Comment: You script doesn't actually do anything except set the value of the current cell to e.value which is what it was  after the edit. What are you expecting it to do?

Answer (score 0):

I added the font change so that I could see the script doing something.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('Entry')
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == 'Sheet0' && e.range.columnStart == 7) {  
    //e.source.toast('flag1');
     e.range.setValue(e.value).setFontWeight('bold');   
  } 
}
```

Tested and Functioning Properly